# How to calculate total wins and losses based on this SQL Table

Tags: sql

I have a table called games(game_id, home_id, home_score, away_id, away_score, date) and a table called team(team_id, team_name). I need a SQL query to calculate the total wins and loss and win % (wins / games played) record for each team based on the home_score and away_score.

`select game_id, home_score, away_score,  case when home_score > away_score then 'true' else 'false ' end from game_schedule`

Tried this but could not get it to do what I want. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Unpivot the data and aggregate:

```
select team_id, sum(is_win) as num_wins, sum(is_loss) as num_losses,
       avg(is_win) as win_ratio
from ((select home_id as team_id,
              (case when home_score > away_score then 1 else 0 end) as is_win,
              (case when home_score < away_score then 1 else 0 end) as is_loss
       from games
      ) union all
      (select away_id,
              (case when away_score > home_score then 1 else 0 end) as is_win,
              (case when away_score < home_score then 1 else 0 end) as is_loss
       from games
      )
     ) g
group by team_id;
```

Comment: I don't see "team" defined anywhere.

Comment: @donPable . . . I fixed the typo.  That should be `team_id`.

Answer (score 0):

Join the tables and use conditional aggregation:

```
select tt.team_id, tt.team_name,
  sum(case when result > 0 then 1 else 0 end) totalwin,
  sum(case when result < 0 then 1 else 0 end) totalloss,
  100.0 * avg(case when result > 0 then 1 else 0 end) percentwin 
from (
  select t.team_id, t.team_name,
    (g.home_score - g.away_score) * case 
      when t.team_id = g.home_id then 1
      when t.team_id = g.away_id then -1
    end result 
  from team t left join games g
  on t.team_id in (g.home_id, g.away_id)
) tt
group by tt.team_id, tt.team_name
```

See a simplified [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/fV733TAGeSCDfCE7ti7Lkx/4).